# What is Equivalent of next in $routeChangeStart in $transitions

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, angular-transitions

I am building a permission-based access control app in angularjs. I want the parameter in $transitions which would be equivalent to 'next' parameter in $routeChangeStart.

```
  function ($rootScope, $state, $transitions, LoginService) {
        console.log('------------------in app.js run');
        $state.go('login');
        $transitions.onStart({}, function ($transitions) {
                var newToState = $transitions.$to();
                if(checkPermissionForView(// param similar to next))
        });

    }
```

I have a service defined which checks if the logged in user has the permission to access the view

```
  checkPermissionForView : function (view) {
                if (!view.requiresAuthentication) {
                    return true;
                }

                return userHasPermissionForView(view);
            }

  userHasPermissionForView : function(view){
                if(!isLoggedIn()){
                    return false;
                }
            }

  isLoggedIn : function () {
                var user = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("user"));
                console.log(user);
                return user != null;
            }
```

As you can see I want to pass 'next' information to service. Does $transitions.$to() yield the same result as next in $routeChangeStart('next')?
I am new to this. TIA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, use `Transition.to()` to get the state that will be activated.

See the [docs for the Transition class](https://ui-router.github.io/ng1/docs/latest/classes/transition.transition-1.html#to) for more details.

```
function ($rootScope, $state, $transitions, LoginService) {
        console.log('------------------in app.js run');
        $state.go('login');
        $transitions.onStart({}, function (transition) {
                var newToState = transition.to();
                if(!checkPermissionForView(newToState)) {
                         return $state.target('login');
                }
        });
}
```

...

```
checkPermissionForView : function (state) {
                if (!state.requiresAuthentication) {
                    return true;
                }

                return userHasPermissionForState(state);
            }

  userHasPermissionForState : function(view){
                if(!isLoggedIn()){
                    return false;
                }
            }

  isLoggedIn : function () {
                var user = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("user"));
                console.log(user);
                return user != null;
            }
```

I highly recommend reading the [Transition Hooks Guide](https://ui-router.github.io/guide/transitionhooks)